# Lucky / Crystal init error: undefined method 'signal' for Process

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to start a new Lucky project and getting an error. I init the project, then cd and ./scripts/setup. Eventually I see the error

In tasks/watch.cr:154:17

154 | process.signal(:term) unless process.terminated?

^-----

Error: undefined method 'signal' for Process

This is OSX 10.15.7, Lucky 0.23.1, crystal 0.34.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted on the Forum, but my guess is something related to the version of Crystal. If you're able to upgrade both Lucky and Crystal to the latest version, that should fix it.